# Changing different variables according to value for efficient code reuse

Tags: java, android, variables, code-reuse

I have variables of type *long*: `hour_6days`, `hour_7days`, `hour_8days` and `hour_13days`.

I have a string array:

```
String[] jj = rule.split(del);
```

where `jj[0]` contains the one of the numbers `6` or `7` or`8` or `13`.

How to change the above long variables according to the value in `jj[0]` ?

For example, how can I write the below, such that right hand side of the assignment is equivalent to the left hand side variable like:

```
hour_6days = "hour_"+jj[0]+"6days"; //this is invalid as hour_6days is of long type.
```

To be more clear,

If `jj[0]` contains `6`, then I will use long variable's `hour_6days` value. If `jj[0]` contains `7`, then I will use the long variable's `hour_7days` value.

The values I am using to set certain TextView like:

```
TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.th3);

tt2.setText(hour_7days);
```

**UPDATE:**

I want to reuse the code in order to avoid multiple conditions. As said, in some conditions I am using `tt2.setText(hour_7days);` and in some other conditions I am using `tt2.setText(hour_6days);` and so on. I want to avoid the conditions and just simple use `tt2.setText(hour_6_or_7_or_8days)`.

Comment: why you using  hour_6days's type long while you trying to store sting in it like hour_6days = "hour_" ?

Comment: Why not have an array `hour_days` and store values of `6days, 7days, etc.` in their respective indexes?

Comment: So, what should the new value of hour_6days be if jj[0] contains "6"? Also, google for "Java naming conventions", read what you'll find, and stick to these conventions. Variables should not contain underscores.

Comment: I can't understand your question. `if(jj[0].equals("6") // use hour_6days else if(jj[0].equals("6") // use hour_7days` ... Is this way you want?

Comment: @JBNizet - No. Understood wrong. If `jj[0]` contains 6, then I will use long variable's `hour_6days` value. If `jj[0]` contains 7, then I will use the long variable's `hour_7days` value. Same for others.

Comment: Your approach may be completely wrong.  Please edit your question to include *what* you are trying to do.  What are you trying to *achieve*?  What are the values of the longs?  For example, what value do `hour_6days` and `hour_7days`have?

Comment: Then define "use". What will you use it for?

Comment: Well, you still haven't said *what* you are trying to do.  I mean a simple explanation, in words and forgetting about the code, why you are doing this.  However, from what you have shown, a `Map` would be a much cleaner solution - http://www.itcuties.com/java/hashmap-example/

Comment: @Simon - I want to reuse the code in order to avoid multiple conditions. As said, in some conditions I am using `tt2.setText(hour_7days);` and in some other conditions I am using `tt2.setText(hour_6days);` and so on. I want to avoid the conditions and just simple use `tt2.setText(hour_6_or_7_or_8days)`.

Comment: Then a `Map` is a great choice.

Comment: Can you just replace all the `hour_n_days` variables with an array of 14 elements, and put the right values into slots 6, 7, 8 and 13 of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Map`, `HashMap` is a possible choice.

```
HashMap<Integer, Long> dayValues = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

dayValues.put(6,  <put long value for 6 days here>);
dayValues.put(7,  <put long value for 7 days here>);
dayValues.put(8,  <put long value for 8 days here>);
dayValues.put(13, <put long value for 13 days here>);

...

tt2.setText(dayValues.get(jj[0]).toString());
```

This will use the integer value in `jj[0]` to get the corresponding string value from the map and set it into `tt2`.

Comment: Ok, `Map` is better than `enum`, as short way. If he uses `final` list of days, `enum` is better; if dynamic - `Map`, +1

Comment: It should be `HashMap<Integer, Long> dayValues = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();` but then I am getting compile time error- `The method add(int, long) is undefined for the type HashMap<Integer,Long>`

Comment: `dayValues.put(6, hour_6days);` worked. Please edit.

Comment: @VedPrakash - thanks, I typed it from memory without an IDE :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you would use `enum`, like:

```
public enum EHourDay{

    hour_6days(6),  // actually I would use Upper case
    hour_7days(7),
    hour_8days(8),
    hour_13days(13);

    public static EHourDay
    FromIntToEnum(
            int value ) throws Exception
            {
        for ( EHourDay c : EHourDay.values() ) {
            if ( c.mId == value ) {
                return c;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception( new StringBuilder("Illegal EHourDay: ").append(value).toString() );
            }

    public int
    FromEnumToInt() {
        return mId;
    }

    private EHourDay( int id )
    {
        mId = id;
    }

    private int mId;
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, Exception {

        String rule = "6 7 8 13";

        String[] jj = rule.split(" ");

        for(String str : jj){
            EHourDay hourDay = EHourDay.FromIntToEnum(Integer.parseInt(str));

            System.out.println(hourDay);
        }

    }
```

After you can type something like:

```
tt2.setText(EHourDay.FromIntToEnum(Integer.parseInt(str)));
```